# ReferenceError: document is not defined in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to show variable 'name' from nodejs in the html p tag with id='name'.
when does the html page gets loaded?

**view.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>TRY</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="name"></p>
</body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="try.js"></script>
</html>
```

**try.js**

```
var http = require ('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var name = "Ronish";
app.use(express.static('public'));
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML=name;
server.listen('3030');
console.log('Listening on port 3030');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are intermixing two things ,server side js and client side js

```
 document.getElementById('name').innerHTML=name;
```

> Above line will not be valid in node js because, `document` object is
>   only available for browsers (client side js)

What you can do to display you variable?
Try template engines like [ejs](https://ejs.co/)

```
var http = require ('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var name = "Ronish";
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));

server.listen('3030');
console.log('Listening on port 3030');

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
res.render("index",{"value":name})

})
```

Then you can display them in your `index.ejs` file

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>TRY</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="name"><%=value %> </p>
</body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="try.js"></script>
</html>
```

For Your [Reference](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) (express routing)